# Simple or BCH Marker Generator

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, markers

I am using the code [here](https://github.com/omeryavuz/VRToolKit) to do some AR on the iPhone, however I am trying to add more markers and even though I went through most of the documentation and code already I can't seem to find how to make these markers, I've Googled for most of the day and I found [an online generator here](http://flash.tarotaro.org/blog/2009/07/12/mgo2/) but either those don't work or I just can't make it work. Any other way you guys might know to generate the markers?

Answer (score -1):

That libray says it uses ARToolKit plus for tracking, and you can download all the ARToolKit plus markers from [here](http://studierstube.icg.tugraz.at/handheld_ar/download/ARToolKitPlus_AllMarkers.zip).